# I want to use a microcontroller with 3.3v outputs with a sensor that needs 3v. Do I need drive-voltage reduction resistors or will be ok?

Tags: arduino, voltage, circuit-design, gas-sensor

I want to use a microcontroller with 3.3 V supply to interface with with an MP-7227-TC sensor that needs a 2.9 to 3.1 V supply voltage.
The sensor is driven by a single high/low conttol line from the microcontroller.

Do I need to reduce the voltage of the control signal or will it be acceptable to drive the sensor directly from the microcontroller?

---

Sensor data:

This information relates to the device operating
continuously in the recommended bridge circuit.

Supply voltage (see note 1)……………. ……2.9 to 3.1V
Sensor current (at 3.0 ± 0.1V)………. …….37 to 41mA

Absolute maximum drive voltage between control pin and ground ………………3.2 V

Link to datasheet:
https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Amphenol%20PDFs/MP-7227-TC.pdf

Comment: Do not use try to use resistors to reduce the supply voltage for the sensor. Add a 1kOhm resistors on the signal lines.

Comment: I have rolled back the latest edit because, while it removed much extraneous material, it also made the question vague enough that some people may possibly not have been able to understand it. The question waa clear enough for spehro to provide a good answer and I found it understandable as-was. || The question is also now self-answering due to my edits retaining only the clarified question and relevant data. || As a consequence of the above changes I have closed and reopened the question as the reasons for the close votes have now been addressed.

Comment: I have heavily edited the question to retain only relevant original data and have clarified the question. || As a consequence of the above changes I have closed and reopened the question as the reasons for the close votes have now been addressedby my editing.

Comment: Marianne - see edits. In future questions try to add useful information BUT also try to exclude irrelevant information which leads to brain-overload for those answering the question. Note also that adding 2 spaces to a line's end before hitting "Enter" allows a new line to start. Lines that do NOT have these spaces at the end prior to "Enter" cause the next line to wrap and give a very messy result.

Comment: **SEPTEMBER 1st** - I rolled back the last edit as, while  it correctly removed much extraneous and badly formated material, it also removed information crucial to understanding the question. I then heavily edited the original material and the question itself. || When making edits please ensure that relevant informatiin is not removed and that the user's intention is at least maintained or, preferably, clarified.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, *adding 2 spaces to a line's end allows a new line to start* You mean "adding 2 newlines". Pressing the space bar twice won't do it.

Comment: @TonyM  I put it wrongly. So did you :-). We both know what we meant :-). I'll edit it.
~~~= "In order to start a new line two spaces have to precede a "new-line"/ Enter ".
|| As with many things, it's far easier to do it than to explain it clearly.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using an [LP3985](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp3985.pdf) or similar LDO 3.0 V regulator (dropout voltage is 100 mV max @ 150 mA, and the unit only draws 37~41 mA so it should be more like 3 5mV). Pay close attention to the datasheet recommendations for capacitors (1 uF minimum ceramic on input and output). That will give you a couple hundred mV for tolerance on both regulators. The LM3985 has 2% tolerance which is 60 mV, so you should be fine with +/-5% tolerance on the 3.3 V supply.

Then you can use a voltage divider to knock down the Arduino GPIO down to about 3 V nominal, say 3 kohms and 30k, for the control input to the [ADG849](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG849.pdf) switch in the sensor.

Assuming you're using 3.3 V for the ADC reference, you can measure both the 3.0 V regulator output and the sensor output and avoid the half-bridge by just multiplying the former by some factor.

The full scale output of the sensor is in the 100 mV range so you won't have a lot of resolution without an amplifier. The temperature output will be fine with the Arduino ADC.

Comment: The 3.3 V on-board regulator, as I just found out [here](https://wspublishing.net/ultimate-uno-manual/preview/), has a tolerance of 1.5%. So as low as 3.25 V to the input of the LDO. It's max current capacity is 150 mA, so the LP3985 seems appropriate from that standpoint, too. And it appears there will be enough overhead voltage for the dropout. And the 2% tolerance looks good. Nice catch!